# How can I override a setuptools command from a setup_require dependancy?

Tags: python, overriding, setuptools

#### Context:

In order to be able to translate GNU gettext po files into mo ones at build time in setuptools, I have created a subclass of `setuptools.command.build_py` that compiles them (through a copy of pymsgfmt) before calling its base class:

```
from setuptools.command.build_py import build_py as _build_py

class build_py(_build_py):
    parent = _build_py
    def run(self):
        self.compile_po_files()  # internal implementation
        self.parent.run(self)

    def get_outputs(self):  # overriden to produce a correct list of installed files
        build_mo = self.get_finalized_command("build_mo")
        return _build_py.get_outputs(self) + self.outputs
```

Then I have only to declare it in the `cmdclass` parameter of `setup`:

```
setup(
    ...
    cmdclass = {"build_py", mypgk.build_py},
)
```

So far, so good, when my module is installed and imported in the `setup.py` script, the build phase of setuptools correctly process my po files.

#### Problem:

The goal would be to allow a simple installation of a source distribution with pip. Things look nice, because pip takes care of any dependency provided they are declared in a `install_requires`, or `setup_requires` parameter. And this is where the chicken and egg problem lies: the dependancy are installed when `setup.py` is runned, but it cannot run without `mypkg` being first installed.

#### Current research:

I have tried to use the magic `entry_points` to declare the `build_py` override in `mypkg` `setup.py` script:

```
...
entry_points = {
    "distutils.commands": [
        "build_py = mypkg:build_py",
        ],
}
```

but it has no effects, while I can declare a working new `build_mo` command that way:

```
entry_points = {
    "distutils.commands": [
        "build_mo = mypkg:build_py",
        ],
}
```

Long story short, `python setup.py build_mo` calls my override, while `python setup.py build_py` calls setuptools version.

#### Question:

Why does my attempt of overriding the `build_py` command with an `entry_points` declaration not work, and how could I do it?

Comment: I use the `build_py` step and not the `build_ext` because I want to be able to produce a platform and version independant wheel. It makes sense because GNU gettext mo files can be used on any platform whatever the endianness.

Comment: From the code you provided, it's not clear why you have to put the custom command in a separate package instead of keeping it in the setup script. As you already discovered, the real issue is that you need to bootstrap the package in order to build or install it. Bootstrapping is a fragile solution - can't you isolate the build code in the setup script instead?

Comment: @hoefling: Because the po to mo compiler is expected to be a package that can be used in other packages. Of course I had included everything in the same package in my very first tests.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Explaining the problem

I was close to the solution. After some more research in `setuptools` docs and sources, I finally realized that it already used the `entry_points` machinery to override `distutils` commands by its own ones.

That means that when you try to override a `setuptools` command, in fact you propose a second override for the same command. Because of the way `setuptools` processes it, only the first override found is used, and from my tests, `setuptools` one is that first.

I can now say that because of that, only commands from `distutils` that are not overriden in `setuptools` can be processed that way. The good news is that `build` is not overriden and that in normal use, `build_py` is always called from `build`.

#### Possible solution:

As the `build` command is not overriden by `setuptools`, it is easy to replace it with an `entry_point`. Then the custom `build` command class can update the `cmdclass` directory to declare the custom `build_py` class because the base `build` loads it. The code can be:

```
from distutils.command.build import build as _build

class build(_build):
    parent = _build
    def run(self):
        self.distribution.cmdclass["build_py"] = build_py
        self.parent.run(self)
```

In my test, it is enough to make `setuptools` use the custom `build_py` class with a simple

```
setup(
    ...
    setup_requires = ["mypkg"],
)
```